# Drawing to the left of x,y coordinates

Tags: qt, drawing, coordinates, qml, qt-quick

I'm working currently on Qt, when i try to draw something (for e.x Rectangle) giving its x,y coordinates & its width & height Qt starts to draw the rectangle starting from its x, y coordinates to the right direction, to demonstrate what I'm talking about see the following picture:

[image: Rect1]

and the following code:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rectangle1
    x: 257
    y: 221
    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: "#000000"
}
```

I would like to know if there is anyway i can start drawing to the left of x,y coordinates, it's like drawing giving the width & height negative values. see the following image for illustration:

[image: Rect2]

I have tried drawing giving the width a negative value, it works fine on the design mode but when i run or debug my application the rectangle does not show up, any ideas on this would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use negative values for this purpose since negative width or height is not supported in QML. But you can use `Scale` type to accomplish this :

```
Rectangle {
    id: rectangle1
    x: 257
    y: 221
    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: "#000000"

    transform: Scale { origin.x: 0; origin.y: 0; xScale: -1}
}
```

`Scale` allows you to scale your item relative to an arbitrary point. Here we scaled the X axis of the item relative to it's interior point (0, 0).

Answer (score 0):

To draw rectangle 50px from the left parent area:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rectangle1
    x: parent.width - 50 // rectangle start 50px from the left
    y: 221  // similar with y pos: parent.height - 50
    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: "#000000"
}
```

But I am not sure If I understood your question properly.

Comment: if you want to draw anything in almost all programming languages you need to specify the position (Coordinates x & y), & then specify the height & width of that object, right? , but the issue is the drawing of that object starts always to the right of the coordinates, is there any function or object that can be used to reverse that & draw to the opposite way (to the left of the coordinates)?, the answer you have mentioned changed the position but the drawing remains from left to right